# How to write a generic apply() function in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming

Is there any way to get the following working in Swift 3?

```
 let button = UIButton().apply {
        $0.setImage(UIImage(named: "UserLocation"), for: .normal)
        $0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(focusUserLocation), 
                     for: .touchUpInside)
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        $0.layer.cornerRadius = 5
     }
```

The `apply<T>` function should take a closure of type `(T)->Void`, run it passing `self` into it, and then simply return `self`.

Another option would be to use an operator for this like "`=>`"
(borrowed the idea from [Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kotlin/info) and [Xtend](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xtend/info) languages).

Tried to do extension of `NSObject` like this:

```
extension NSObject {   
    func apply<T>(_ block: (T)->Void) -> T
    {
        block(self as! T)
        return self as! T
    }
}
```

But it requires explicit declaration of the parameter type in closure:

```
let button = UIButton().apply { (it: UIButton) in
        it.setImage(UIImage(named: "UserLocation"), for: .normal)
        it.addTarget(self, action: #selector(focusUserLocation), 
                     for: .touchUpInside)
        ...
```

This is not convenient and makes the whole idea not worth the effort. The type is already specified at object creation and it should be possible not to repeat it explicitly.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm still getting comfortable with generics in Swift myself. However, you couldn't do what you're trying to do with any `NSObject`.  The `addTarget(_:for:)` method is defined in UIControl, and `setImage(_:for:)` is specific to `UIButton`.

Comment: You're right, that's exactly why I'd like to get the concrete type (perhaps as a generic type argument) into the apply() function declaration. Then static type checking won't allow me to call wrong methods.

Comment: https://github.com/iwheelbuy/Decorator if it is good enough for your - I can post an answer

Comment: @iWheelBuy: That's a very nice library, perhaps I'll use it, thanks! However it doesn't answer the asked question but rather pushes the problem upstream (definitions of Styles require repeating explicit types in closures)

Comment: @AlexJenter if you have a ```UIButton()``` and want to configure it with apply, then no Style is required. just call ```button.decorator.apply```

Comment: @AlexJenter If you want to style buttons, why don't you create subclasses?

Comment: @iWheelBuy: I see. Thanks.

Comment: @Sulthan: That would be an option of course. But I wanted to know if this was possible. Note that it can be handy for non-UI objects as well.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### The HasApply protocol

First of all lets define the `HasApply` protocol

```
protocol HasApply { }
```

and related extension

```
extension HasApply {
    func apply(closure:(Self) -> ()) -> Self {
        closure(self)
        return self
    }
}
```

Next let make `NSObject` conform to `HasApply`.

```
extension NSObject: HasApply { }
```

### That's it

Let's test it

```
let button = UIButton().apply {
    $0.titleLabel?.text = "Tap me"
}

print(button.titleLabel?.text) // Optional("Tap me")
```

### Considerations

> I wouldn't use `NSObject` (it's part of the Objective-C way of doing things and I assume it will be removed at some point in the future). I would prefer something like `UIView` instead.

```
extension UIView: HasApply { }
```

Comment: That's genius. It works. Thanks! I'll accept this answer because it most directly answers the asked question. However asnwers of Alain T. and iWheelBuy are great as well.

Comment: Nice simple use of closures. (Voted.) I was over-thinking it. Well done

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and ended up solving it with an operator:

```
infix operator <-< : AssignmentPrecedence
func <-<<T:AnyObject>(left:T, right:(T)->()) -> T
{
  right(left)
  return left
}

let myObject = UIButton() <-< { $0.isHidden = false }
```

Comment: Wow, really nice, thanks! This has the added benefit that it doesn't require the type to be a descendant of NSObject or UIView.

Answer (score 8):

There's a [very good and simple Cocoapods library](https://github.com/devxoul/Then) available called `Then` that does exactly that. Only that it uses `then` instead of `apply`. Simply import `Then` and *then* you can do as the OP asked for:

```
import Then

myObject.then {
    $0.objectMethod()
}

let label = UILabel().then {
    $0.color = ...
}
```

Here's how the protocol is implemented: https://github.com/devxoul/Then/blob/master/Sources/Then/Then.swift

```
extension Then where Self: Any {
    public func then(_ block: (Self) throws -> Void) rethrows -> Self {
        try block(self)
        return self
    }
```

Comment: Very nice library! Also adds handy "with" and "do" methods. Thanks a lot

Comment: Probably worth noting: this doesn't really get around the limitations to extending `Any`. They just manually extend a whole bunch of different types to conform to `Then`.

Answer (score 1):

Alain has a good answer if you're not allergic to custom operators.  If you'd rather not use those, the best alternative I could come up with was:

```
@discardableResult func apply<T>(_ it:T, f:(T)->()) -> T {
    f(it)
    return it
}
```

which then allows you to use:

```
let button = apply(UIButton()) { $0.setTitleText("Button") }
```

It's not quite the same, but works out pretty well in general and has the advantage that T is completely unrestrained. It's an obviously contrived example, but:

```
func apply<T,R>(_ it:T, f:(T)->R) -> R {
    return f(it)
}
```

even allows:

```
print("\(apply(32) { $0 + 4 })")
```

Answer (score 0):

**In case of object which must be created with non optional init:**

```
let button = UIButton()
Optional(button).map {
    $0.isEnabled = true
}
```

**In case of object which must be created with optional init:**

```
let button = UIButton(coder: coder)
button.map {
    $0.isEnabled = true
}
```

**In case of existing optional object we can use map function:**

```
optionalObject.map {
    $0.property1 = true
    $0.property2 = true
}
```

**If object must be cast before being use:**

```
(optionalObject as? NewType).map {
    $0.property1 = true
    $0.property2 = true
}
```