# `map` function for non-collection types in Swift

Tags: swift, functional-programming

Swift has [several high-order functions](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/higher-order-functions-in-swift-filter-map-reduce-flatmap-1837646a63e8) like `map` which encourage functional programming paradigms (e.g. chaining functions together).

For example:

```
users                                         // e.g. [User]
  .map(Person(from:))                         // e.g. protocol Person { init(from: User) }
  .map { $0.name }                            // e.g. protocol Person { var name: String { get } }
  .map(Person.normalizedName(fromName:))      // e.g. protocol Person { static func normalizedName(fromName: String) -> String }
  .map(User(username:)                        // e.g. protocol User { init(username: String) }
```

This works because it started with an array of `[User]` and each element was mutated along the way.

---

Now imagine we're trying to manipulate a `CGPoint` instead of an array with the following traditional code:

```
let point: CGPoint = input
let flippedPoint = CGPoint.flipHorizontally(point)
let halvedPoint = CGPoint(x: flippedPoint.x / 2.0, y: flippedPoint.y)
let rect = CGRect(at: halvedPoint)
```

This code is disadvantageous because: (A) it requires coming up with an intermediary variable name at each step of the function, and (B) you can easily make a logic error that compiles just fine (e.g. `CGPoint(x: point.x / 2.0, y: flippedPoint.y)`).

You could attempt to solve (A) by chaining it all on one line:

```
CGRect(at: CGPoint(x: CGPoint.flipHorizontally(point).x / 2.0, y: CGPoint.flipHorizontally(point).y))
```

However, this is messy, and even more error prone (e.g. notice the two calls that need to be made to `CGPoint.flipHorizontally(point)`.

---

Now imagine what it would look like if you could call `map` on a `CGPoint`:

```
point                                          // e.g. CGPoint
  .map(CGPoint.flipHorizontally(_:))           // e.g. extension CGPoint { static func flipHorizontally(_ point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint }
  .map { CGPoint(x: $0.x / 2.0, y: $0.y) }
  .map(CGRect.init(at:))                       // e.g. extension CGRect { init(at: CGPoint) }
```

That code is much cleaner than either of the two alternatives.

---

**Is there any way to call `map` (or other high-order functions) on a non-collection type?**

---

I realize one workaround is to wrap/unwrap in an array, but I'm hoping there is a less clunky way:

```
[point]                                          
  .map(CGPoint.flipHorizontally(_:))           
  .map { CGPoint(x: $0.x / 2.0, y: $0.y) }
  .map(CGRect.init(at:))                       
  .first!
```

A second workaround is to wrap in `Optional`, but this only allows `map` and `flatMap` and is also clunky:

```
Optional(point)
  .map(CGPoint.flipHorizontally(_:))           
  .map { CGPoint(x: $0.x / 2.0, y: $0.y) }
  .map(CGRect.init(at:))!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are asking to program in a functional style. Isn't it just a question of arming yourself with functions beforehand? Unclear what your posted `flipHorizontally` and `init(at:)` are actually supposed to *do*, but let's just make up some fake functionality for them. Then if these are common things to do, you could inject them into CGPoint as extensions, as you suggested:

```
extension CGPoint {
    func flipHorizontally() -> CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x:y, y:x) // or whatever
    }
    func halvedPoint() -> CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x:x/2.0, y:y)
    }
    func makeRect(at:CGPoint) -> CGRect {
        CGRect(origin:at, size:CGSize(width:100,height:100))
        // or whatever
    }
}
```

And there's your chain:

```
let r =
    CGPoint(x:7,y:9)
        .flipHorizontally()
        .halvedPoint()
        .makeRect()
```

---

But if those are not common things to do and you want to express them functionally at the point of use (through anonymous functions, like with `map`), then you could start with this sort of extension:

```
extension CGPoint {
    func munge<T>(f:(CGPoint)->T) -> T {
        f(self)
    }
}
```

And now you can talk like this:

```
let r =
    CGPoint(x:7,y:9)
        .munge { CGPoint(x:$0.y, y:$0.x) }
        .munge { CGPoint(x:$0.x/2.0, y:$0.y) }
        .munge { CGRect(origin:$0, 
                          size:CGSize(width:100,height:100))}
```

That's a very map-like chain, surely.

---

You asked whether you'd have to write an extension for every type you wanted to inject `munge` into. Not exactly; you could just write a generic protocol and have all those types adopt the protocol:

```
protocol Mungeable {
    func munge<T>(f:(Self)->T) -> T
}
extension Mungeable {
    func munge<T>(f:(Self)->T) -> T {
        f(self)
    }
}
extension CGPoint:Mungeable {}
// and so too for other types
```

---

Finally I should point out that the Combine framework does let you do exactly what you're describing, *actually using the word `map`*, even though that is not the Combine framework's intent:

```
var r : CGRect!
_ = Just(CGPoint(x:7,y:9))
    .map { CGPoint(x:$0.y, y:$0.x) }
    .map { CGPoint(x:$0.x/2.0, y:$0.y) }
    .map { CGRect(origin:$0, size:CGSize(width:100,height:100)) }
    .sink {r = $0}
```

Comment: I dig the name `munge`! Is there a good way to `munge` any datatype, not just `CGPoint`? Or would I need to add that extension manually on every data type I intend to `munge`? (e.g. CGRect, UIEdgeInset, User, Person, etc.)

Comment: Note additional edit demonstrating that the Combine framework sort of has this built right in.

Comment: Further edit showing how to use a protocol to inject `munge` everywhere you need it.

Comment: Oops looks like we didn’t invent this. It’s called `apply` and everyone knows about it already. Example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830927/how-to-write-a-generic-apply-function-in-swift